# How to access message key inside the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to access 'message' key value in this list of dictionaries, but can't figure out how to do it.

```
events [{'logStreamName': 'omkar/default/c09fabdb-c8f6-4e2b-935d-d8acd81fe5b6',
 'timestamp': 1581492608825, 'message': 'initial_run.py', 'ingestionTime': 1581492608977, 'eventId':
 '35268463702765787750672147556453127148731795119999483904'}, {'logStreamName':
 'omkar/default/c09fabdb-c8f6-4e2b-935d-d8acd81fe5b6', 'timestamp': 1581492608825,
 'message': 'initial_run.sh', 'ingestionTime': 1581492608977, 'eventId': '35268463702765787750672147556453127148731795119999483905'}, {'logStreamName':
 'omkar/default/c09fabdb-c8f6-4e2b-935d-d8acd81fe5b6', 'timestamp': 1581492608825,
 'message': 'second_script.sh', 'ingestionTime': 1581492608977, 'eventId': '35268463702765787750672147556453127148731795119999483906'}, {'logStreamName': 'omkar/default/c09fabdb-c8f6-4e2b-935d-d8acd81fe5b6', 'timestamp': 1581492608865,
 'message': 'in python output_2 hello output_2', 'ingestionTime': 1581492608977, 'eventId': '35268463703657817558613372482114555879637729580238700547'}, {'logStreamName': 'omkar/default/c09fabdb-c8f6-4e2b-935d-d8acd81fe5b6', 'timestamp': 1581492608866, 'message': 'output_2', 'ingestionTime': 1581492608977,
 'eventId': '35268463703680118303811903105256091597910377941744680964'}, {'logStreamName': 'omkar/default/c09fabdb-c8f6-4e2b-935d-d8acd81fe5b6', 'timestamp': 1581492608868, 'message': '/usr/local/bin/initial_run.py', 'ingestionTime': 1581492608977, 'eventId': '35268463703724719794208964351539163034455674664756641797'}]
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of message values by using list comprehension -

```
message_list = [x['message'] for x in events]
```

*This assumes that a message key always exists for each entry in event. If it does not you may need to use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: it is actually nested dic..message key is inside the event key..and want to access value of message key

Comment: @swapnildeshpande Firstly your initial question has no mention of a nested dictionary, secondly this will still work as all it needs is access to whatever is in events. It will give you a list of all the value of `message` in the list of dictionaries

Comment: @swapnildeshpande I edited my code to include accessing values from `response10` (which you mentioned in a comment to another answer) to make it more clear

Answer (score 2):

```
for ev in event:
...     print(ev['message'])
...
```

iterate over event anf inside you can get by using key (meassage)

Comment: ev is normal varible which will hold each dictinory one by one exist in your event list

Comment: its giving me typeerror :String indices must be integers

Comment: paste your code, what you have done. because it working here and print value of message key one by one

Comment: 'response10 = client1.filter_log_events(
    logGroupName='/aws/batch/job',
    # logStreamNames=[
    #     'omkar/default',
    # ],
    logStreamNamePrefix='omkar/default',
    # startTime=123,
    # endTime=123,
    # filterPattern='string',
    # nextToken='string',
    # limit=123,
    # interleaved=True|False 
    )    print(response10)'........response10 is name of our nested dic

Comment: @swapnildeshpande you can edit your question and add in your code instead of adding it as a comment where your limited by the number of characters, furthermore all three answers here so far get you all the values of `message` from the list of dictionaries that you have provided, choose whichever you like the most and try implementing it

Comment: if response10 is your data, then for response in response10:  print(response['message']) ,

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
res=list(map(lambda x:x['message'],events))
print(res)
#['initial_run.py', 'initial_run.sh', 'second_script.sh', 'in python output_2 hello output_2', 'output_2', '/usr/local/bin/initial_run.py']
```

---

If you dont want to use `lambda` you can use `itemgetter`.

```
from operator import itemgetter
res=list(map(itemgetter('message'),events))
```

Comment: Just curious, is mapping in this manner faster than regular list comprehension ?

Comment: there is no solid fact that among filter, map and list comprehension what is fasted. However, in most of the cases, list comprehensions are fastest and the filter is slowest. But there may be use cases when list comprehensions are actually slower @KaranShishoo

Comment: Unless performance really matter on this block of code (in a very used function for example), prefer list comprehension which is more concise and readable.

Comment: @DorianTurba Agreed, I would have mentioned solution using list comprehension but it's already posted by someone. As I don't want to post a duplicate solution.So, posted alternative solution. If you think it's better I should post then I'll post it and add credits.

Comment: In fact, it's the opposite: "Besides the syntactic benefit of list comprehensions, they are often as fast or faster than equivalent use of map." - https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops So yes, you should use list comprehension instead. This is a valid answer, so keep it as it is, but less pythonic and optimized than list comprehension.